# What is this strange screen I'm stuck into; no response to any touch [LineageOS, HCT M8]

Tags: htc, lineageos

HTC One M8 with LineageOS 15.0 (custom ROM, has always worked well until now).

Suddenly I only see this screen: 5:37 (the time it got stuck) in cyan dots, and a field of green and white dots (possibly a big battery icon).

Phone doesn't respond to touching touchscreen, or even the hardware buttons. Tried to press Power to turn the phone off, but nothing happens.

I was doing nothing in particular with the phone when or before this happened, just woke it up from sleep and found it in this state.

What is this screen?

How to get out of this?

Could this even be a virus or other malware maybe?

[image]

Comment: Can you pull the battery and restart?

Comment: No, the battery is non-removable in this phone... Tried the Power-off button but it doesn't react to that, so I might have to just wait until the battery runs empty (might take very long, it was full when this happened).

Comment: Try holding both POWER and VOL_UP (or VOL_DOWN) simultaneously. There are also reports that you'll need to do it in an environment with adequate lighting. If successful the phone should vibrate then reboot.

Comment: Power + Volume-Up did restart the phone, but indeed only in bright lightning.

Answer (score 2):

This is a screen corresponding to the [HTC Dot View Case](https://www.androidcentral.com/dot-view-case) - normally you should be seeing this screen through the case's lid when it's closed, so it will provide clock, notification, etc. at a glance. This screen appearing in normal use likely means that your device's Hall (magnetic) sensor, responsible for detecting cover lid status, is malfunctioning.

You should still be able to forcefully reboot - try holding both POWER and VOL_UP simultaneously under adequate lighting (to trigger the ambient light sensor, so it won't think the button combination was mispressed and prevent the reboot). If successful the phone should vibrate then reboot.

If a reboot doesn't remedy the problem, boot into a custom recovery (assuming you're using TWRP). From there mount `/system` and use the built-in file manager to find and remove an app named `FlipFlap` inside `/system/app` or `/system/priv-app`. That specific app is responsible for displaying the screen you see.

If that still doesn't solve the problem, you either need a LOS build that disables the Hall sensor entirely, or have the device repaired.

Comment: In the mean time, to further verify if it's actually a sensor problem, you can also try flashing other ROMs, preferably Sense-based ones.

Comment: So it restarted by pressing Power + Volume-Up in bright lightning. It restarted normally and is functioning normally as of now, so I didn't have to do what you describe in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: @LB7979 Good to know then - I was expecting the sensor to keep malfunctioning. I'll slightly edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @AndyYan oh man you saved me from going insane because of this useless `FlipFlap` junk app :D removing the app seems have solved the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue - I'm using "Lineage" - Just the power button for 10 secs reboots mine. Might be magnetic car holder causing mine.